# createMinToInstruction authorized by PDA, works fine in LocalNet, but gives "Account not associated with this Mint" when run on DevNet

Tags: anchor, linux-mint, solana

I create an automate deployment script that will mint 2million SPL tokens to an address, the mint is owned by the program PDA as shown in Solana explorer:

[image: 1]

Bellow is the last step in the deployment script:

```
export async function mint2e6Tokens(provider: anchor.AnchorProvider, tokenAccount: PublicKey, mint: PublicKey): Promise<void> {
  // get the token account could be PDA
  const programKeypair = await createKeypairFromFile(PROGRAM_KEYPAIR_PATH);
  /** Load from PDA */
  let mint_tokens_tx = new Transaction().add(
    createMintToInstruction(
      mint,
      tokenAccount,
      programKeypair.publicKey, // -> I DOUBLE CHECKED, THIS IS 6Z24B3qCrWfWvDo1f2HgxmnBSGhqQes1sHobqMtMxfbP
      2e6,
      [],
      TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
    )
  );
  // We sign with our programId instead of the wallet because this is a PDA
  // Program Derived Adress
  await provider.sendAndConfirm(mint_tokens_tx, [programKeypair]);
}
```

When I run in LocalNet, it works:

```
Migrating to LocalNet...
RUNNING CUSTOM SCRIPT ====>>> 
Payper: EsgJ9ihTEZskWyWpMMPuGVisy5ay76YWgetgTLb3jRmj
Using program 6Z24B3qCrWfWvDo1f2HgxmnBSGhqQes1sHobqMtMxfbP
Program: 6Z24B3qCrWfWvDo1f2HgxmnBSGhqQes1sHobqMtMxfbP
Mint: AVPgrT1y6ZfjGWPyLCWEPZdogRgmEMbrdRbcHNSfAPzF
Campaign: FcAmyEgZsXUKLB6hKufDmLuSBzMzVtPmRPm7vZLStK4U
31999500
```

However when I switch to DevNet, it always give me error

```
Migrating to DevNet...
RUNNING CUSTOM SCRIPT ====>>> 
Payper: EsgJ9ihTEZskWyWpMMPuGVisy5ay76YWgetgTLb3jRmj
Using program 6Z24B3qCrWfWvDo1f2HgxmnBSGhqQes1sHobqMtMxfbP
Program: 6Z24B3qCrWfWvDo1f2HgxmnBSGhqQes1sHobqMtMxfbP
Mint: AVPgrT1y6ZfjGWPyLCWEPZdogRgmEMbrdRbcHNSfAPzF
Campaign: FcAmyEgZsXUKLB6hKufDmLuSBzMzVtPmRPm7vZLStK4U
SendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x3
    at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (/code/beens/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:4248:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Connection.sendRawTransaction (/code/beens/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:4210:20)
    at async sendAndConfirmRawTransaction (/code/beens/node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/provider.ts:288:21)
    at async AnchorProvider.sendAndConfirm (/code/beens/node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/provider.ts:148:14) {
  logs: [
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [1]',
    'Program log: Instruction: MintTo',
    'Program log: Error: Account not associated with this Mint',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 2809 of 200000 compute units',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA failed: custom program error: 0x3'
  ]
}
```

Why the authority is right, but Solana complain that **Error: Account not associated with this Mint**?

Comment: you should deploy your program to devnet first and take another program address. finally you have two addresses for localnet and devnet.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my versions for Solana, Anchor and Rust are not compatible with DevNet and / or testnet.

I upgrade solana to main net recommended version and it works. One more things to mention that don't forget to run "solana program close --buffers" before trying. My current settings are:

```
root@d4c64206ce03:/code# solana --version
solana-cli 1.10.31 (src:77a40cd8; feat:4192065167)
root@d4c64206ce03:/code# rustc --version
rustc 1.63.0 (4b91a6ea7 2022-08-08)
root@d4c64206ce03:/code# anchor --version
anchor-cli 0.25.0
```